# Django display formated string with tuple data (called only once)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to display tuple data in a django template.

I want to use a syntax like the Python formated string :

```
print("I have %d referrers and %f cashbacks" % request.user.get_referrer_data())
```

In this case, `request.user.get_referrer_data()` is an expensive method, so I want called it only once in my template (despite the fact that I cache its result).

Do you know a template syntax that let me inject a tuple in a string ?

A code like that would be great :

```
{{ "I have %d referrers and %f cashbacks" | formated_string request.user.get_referrer_data() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{% with ...`

```
{% with rdata=request.user.get_referrer_data %}

I have {{ rdata.0 }} referrers and {{ rdata.1 }} cashbacks

{% endwith %}
```

To get greater control over the formatting of the values use a filter. Django provides `floatformat` for float values:

```
{{ rdata.1|floatformat:2 }}
```

gives two decimal places.

Comment: Big thanks it's perfect. It require just no spaces near = sign.

Comment: There's an alternative syntax `with request.user.get_referrer_data as rdata` if you want spaces. I don't think it's deprecated, though it's referred to as "old syntax" in new docs.